# PcapDotNet An attempt was made to load a program with > an incorrect format

Tags: c#, winpcap, pcap.net

I'm attempting to use the pcapDotNet library to my project, however, I get an exception when launching the appliction. I'm using Visual Studio 2010, winpcap 4.1.3 and PcapDotNet 1.0.2.21772.

The exception is:

> Could not load file or assembly 'PcapDotNet.Core,
>   Version=1.0.2.21772, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=4b6f3e583145a652'
>   or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with
>   an incorrect format.

Comment: Add tags. Make title more searchable. Edit grammar to clarify text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used 32 bit dll file  and my problem solved.